# Separate mobile website. Building from scratch

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, responsive-design

I want to learn some more about developing for mobile devices.

I've googled a lot around and also searches in here. But a lot of the topics are about turning your exitsting website into a mobile version, using responsive design and so on.

But that's not what I want to learn.. For the practice of it, I just want to develop to a mobile platform with no desktop version.

I've also checked links like: http://jquerymobile.com/

But I want to learn how to build it from scratch myself.

Can anyone provide me with some good links to tutorials, guides etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean from scratch? Don't you want tools like jquery mobile?

Comment: I want a tutorial where I can build it myself, and not use the drag-and-drop UI builder in jquery mobile. I can offcourse still use the libary. I just want a more step by step approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building a mobile site is not an easy task. First of all you have to have priorities.

1. Which devices do you want to support (old ones, new ones, what
   capabilities they must absolutely have. You can't expect all of them
   to offer the same speed and responsiveness)?
2. Which operating systems and what versions of them?
3. Which browsers? (This is very important. Although web apps run on
   multiple devices and OSs, you have to keep in mind that they are
   running inside the browser, and they tend to differ)
4. What is your background as a developer?

There are a lot of ways for building a mobile site. One thing is certain though. Since you are an individual you will have to use some framework that offers a big amount of functionality.
Reinventing the wheel is not the way to go. You will have to take care a lot of problems that are hardware dependent and you don't want that. Asking for a tutorial in general is not helping. First of all you have to read the docs and examples. jquery mobile and 
sencha touch have amazing documentation and lots of examples. You don't need more than that to start exploring. When you are stuck with a problem then you visit their forums and stackoverflow for assistance on specific matters. Since you don't know about mobile development I would suggest you start with jquery mobile. It's very easy if you have some knowledge of jquery and html. You will have results immediately. The docs have examples for your first page and after that you can begin adding things.

//EDIT What you say about the builder for jquery mobile is misguiding. You don't have to use any builder for jquery mobile. You can write it yourself. Check the documentation.